# Sinatra and Ruby error: ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique at /shoes/1

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra

Good morning, I'm using Sinatra and Ruby to create a running app that logs your runs. I keep getting this error anytime I try to save a run:

`ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique at /shoes/1`

Here is my controller for this route:

```
post '/shoes/:id' do
@shoe = Shoe.find(params[:id])
if logged_in?
  @runs = @shoe.runs.build(params)
  @newest_run = (@shoe.current_mileage.to_i + @runs.latest_run.to_i)
  @shoe.current_mileage = @newest_run
  @runs.save
  flash[:message] = "A new run has been added!"
  redirect to("/shoes/#{@shoe.id}")
else
  redirect to("/login")
end
```

end

I've been trying to debug this all morning and can't find the reason as to why the run can't happen. I have 3 models as well: A user has_many shoes; a shoe belongs_to a user and has_many runs; a run belongs_to a shoe. Could there be an issue with the associations I have set up?

Edited: Here is my schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20200708142633) do

  create_table "runs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "latest_run"
    t.date    "date"
    t.string  "location"
    t.integer "shoe_id"
  end

  create_table "shoes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string  "name"
    t.date    "date"
    t.integer "new_mileage"
    t.integer "current_mileage"
    t.integer "latest_run"
    t.decimal "price",           precision: 10, scale: 3
    t.integer "user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "username"
    t.string "email"
    t.string "password_digest"
  end

end
```

Edited #2:

Here are my params:
`{"latest_run"=>"150", "location"=>"Kansas", "date"=>"2020-07-07", "id"=>"1"}`

Here is are my Shoe and Run models:

```
class Shoe < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :runs
    validates :name, :date, :new_mileage, :current_mileage, :price, presence: true
end


class Run < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :shoe
    validates_presence_of :latest_run, :date, :location, :shoe_id
end
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: could you add your db schema? looks like there's a constraint there, maybe in `runs` table, that doesn't allow to insert duplicated data

Comment: Just added - thanks!

Comment: could you add an example of `params` as well? maybe it's missing something

Comment: In your `Shoe` or `Run` model in Rails, you have likely defined some unique constraint which is violated here. Please add the model classes.

Comment: Hi everyone, models and params have been added. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: ok, looking at params, i think the problem is with  `id`  key, it's trying to create new run with id `1` and that one exists already in your dd, can you try removing that key from params?

Comment: @mr_sudaca, thank you! Everything is now fixed! :)